# Why can't I select any stackExchange site for migration?

Tags: feature-request, flagging

It's really bugging me. There's a question that I believe belongs on a stackExchange site 
which is not included in the list below:

[image: Standard flagging popup]

Who has created that list anyway? Why can't I see any *Search* field?

Comment: Thank you for giving me appropriate feedback on *my first post here* after downvoting.

Comment: Downvoting on Meta is usually just an expression of (dis)agreement with a post's premises or the usefulness of a feature you're requesting. Don't take it personally.

Comment: I was not directly requesting feature, rather asking why it's vacant. Only if nobody can provide reasonable answer why the feature should not exist it becomes a serious feature request. But I understand I used tag `feature-request` rather than `discussion`.

Answer (score 6):

It is created and maintained by the devs, with collaboration from the community and mods. This is because mods typically ask the mods on sites where we *think* a question may be on topic, and move accordingly.

Not everyone reads the help center for the sites they are trying to send a question to, so we only maintain a small list for regular users to migrate to.

If you feel it belongs on a site not listed, feel free to Flag for Moderator attention (**after reading the destination site's Help Center**), and they can make the call. Option two (and usually faster) is to come into the [Ask a SU Mod chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114/ask-a-super-user-moderator), and ask there.

Comment: Actually no - as far as I recall, its set by the devs, and when SF wanted to be removed from SO, they needed to ask. Flagging is the superior option, assuming the question isn't crap.

Comment: If there's an option, I'm not really aware of it. I'll give the more experienced mods a poke in the morning.

Comment: I'm waiting for the confirmation then.

Comment: Nonetheless, you can flag such a question - there's no way to arbitrarily search, and flag to migrate to a site thats on the list. However, if the mod who's handling decides the question is of low quality, it may not be migrated. Likewise, migrations can be rejected at the target site.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek It seems that option has disappeared for me, so nevermind! Updated the answer anyways

Answer (score 3):

This was [brought up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86928/migrate-to-any-site) on Meta Stack Exchange a few years back. The main reasoning for not adding more was:

> Adding even more migration paths to this existing close list would clutter the UI. The idea is to show the most frequent migration paths so the users to can migrate most questions.

Along with a variety of other reasons that were brought up. Here's a few more:

> Unless you are very familiar with the community that will be receiving the question, you should not be migrating it there. Moderators can get in touch with other moderators on the receiving site when in doubt.
>
> Questions not in the given paths to migrate should not be migrated unless there is a compelling reason to do so. The end result of a migration is ensuring that a question gets more high quality answers faster than it would otherwise.

Comment: Hmm good find, but personally I can't agree with listed the arguments. Cluttered UI could be prevented with a search/filter control. And I don't want to know how often a semi-optimal migration site is selected, because the best match isn't even on the list (or the reviewer isn't aware of it). And AFAIK since several reviewers have to agree on the migration, there is a good chance a question won't be ending up on a totally wrong site.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason for the limited list is that we do not migrate questions to Stack Exchange sites that are in Beta. So, only the well-established related SE sites are listed.

Comment: That's quite not an answer. I do understand that `Beta` sites are not listed. But almost **all** sites are not listed. One could easily create a list to search only through "*well-estabilished*" sites.

Comment: That's because **most** sites in Stack Exchange are *still* in Beta.